# Return key and value from object if value equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

Can I return just the key/value pair from an object with multiple keys when `typeof value` equals something?

```
 var recs = {
                "user_name": "C_51",
                "num1": 51,
                "num2": 101,
                "num3": 151
            },
            {
                "metric": 4461996.0,
                "title": "v_revenue"
            }
```

```
Object.values(recs).forEach(k => {
    if (typeof k == 'string') {
        //then show:
        {"user_name": "C_51"},
       {"title": "v_revenue"}
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `recs` is a syntax error.

Comment: The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values.  You're understanding is wholly incorrect. See [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: @StackSlave it's a logic error not a syntax error. `if (typeof Object.values(recs) == 'string')` is a legit line of code - it simply will always be false.

Comment: I edited it. I had done a forEach and then looped through each

Comment: @RamblinRose and OP, that first block of code is an invalid Object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is ... a little messy.  But the core idea of what you want to do isn't hard.

If you have:

```
const recs = {
    "user_name": "C_51",
    "num1": 51,
    "num2": 101,
    "num3": 151
};
```

You can do ...

```
const entries = Object.entries(recs);
const entryObjects = entries.map(name, value) => ({ [name]: value });
```

and then entryObjects will be an array of objects made out of the "entries" of `recs`.

Comment: @machineghost, But I just want the strings. I don't want "num1": 51,
    "num2": 101,
    "num3": 151 I just want "user_name": "C_51"

Comment: Oh, well it's even simpler then: `const { user_name } = recs; const yourNewObject = { user_name };`.  If you have other properties you care about you just add them inside, eg. `const { user_name, foo } = recs; const yourNewObject = { foo, user_name };`